# Booting Problem Ubuntu 17.10 on Second Hard Drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, boot-repair

First of all: excuse me for my bad English and missing Linux knowledge.

I've tried to install Ubuntu 17.10 on the second Hard Drive of my Notebook (the first one only has 128gb) and it seems to be successfully installed, but didn't boot.

I changed the boot-order, disabled Secure-Boot and disabled Fast-Startup, but Windows 10 still boot's.

Then I ran boot-repair on a live system and it gave me [this link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26225352/) with the boot information (?) of my notebook, so more professional people can see it :)

And Unfortunately it also did not work after boot-repair.

Maybe more information: there are 2 hard drives

- one 128gb SSD with Windows (and it's completely full)
- and a 1TB HDD, that has 250gb free Space at the beginning for Ubuntu.

The Ubuntu Installation has

- a 350mb EFI Partition
- 4gb SWAP
- and the rest (around 200gb) `\`-Partition.

During the Installation I selected the second Hard-Drive (`sdb`) for the Boot-Loader-Installation

Here some pictures of the actual Boot-priority-Order and the Boot Option Menu:
Boot_Priority_Order
[image: Boot_Priority_Order]

Boot_Manager
[image: Boot_Manager]

Comment: Entering your BIOS/UEFI does your Ubuntu at all appear in the boot options?

Comment: @derHugo i hope i understand your question right. Do you mean with Boot-Options the same menu, where you select the USB-Stick that should be booted? Then: No, only my first hard Drive appears in this menu (and USB-Sticks, if there are some)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everyone and thanks for every comment/answer :)

I solved the Problem and wanted to describe here.

The Main Problem is, that i have a Acer Laptop (Acer Aspire V Nitro vn7 572g 70bv). But i think many Acer Laptops has the same Problems.

For the Installation i minimized the Second Hard Drive by 200gb and created the following Partitions (`fdisk -l` - output):

`Disk /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F9FD3CB3-D776-4577-95EB-2AEC38CB1189
Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1  406335488 1953523711 1547188224 737,8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2       2048       4095       2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb3       4096     491519     487424   238M EFI System
/dev/sdb4     491520    8304639    7813120   3,7G Linux swap
/dev/sdb5    8304640    8890367     585728   286M Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb6    8890368  406335487  397445120 189,5G Linux filesystem`

Maybe you are wondering why sdb1 is starting so far away from the beginning.
I moved it with GParted on a Live System because i thought it would help. Now i think it is not necessary.

(as soon as a can i will add here a GParted Screenshot, that i don't have at the moment) But i only followed the standard Ubuntu Installation. So just read the Official Articles around Partitioning :)

I had the Problem, that after a successful install Windows booted anyway.

[The Solution of this Post worked for me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815027/ubuntu-16-04-wont-boot-when-installed-after-windows-10)

[This is a Post also describes the/a Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771455/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-on-acer-aspire/771749#771749)

The Trick is, that Acer won't boot Ubuntu, if Secure-Boot is disabled.
So -> turning it on and selecting the right EFI-File(s) for booting, solve this Problem.

Thank you Internet ^^

Comment: For everyone, who reads this and is trying to install Ubuntu: 350mb for the efi Partition is to little. I really had problems upgrading to 18.04, because on the boot partition didn't was enough space. (I must compress the existing files). Choose at least 400 mb or better 500.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, which device for boot loader installation, you selected at the time of installing Ubuntu 17.10 on second hard disk ? (as shows in below image)

[image]

It is important to select second hard disk device node for boot loader installation of Ubuntu 17.10, not first hard disk device node. In most cases, sda for first hard disk and sdb for second hard disk. So, you have to select sdb for boot loader installation for Ubuntu 17.10 for installing MBR details of on second hard disk.

After this, open the BIOS setting and change the boot disk priority. Give first/highest priority to second hard disk(which contains Ubuntu 17.10) and then first hard disk(which contains Windows).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering :D <p> And sorry that i forgot to write this information in my question. <p> I selected `sdb` (The second Hard Drive) for the Boot Loader Installation. And i already give the second drive the highest priority. (I can add some images to my question) <p> And i am wondering why in the boot-repair on line 6+7 stand: `=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.` Did Microsoft doesn't wrote something in the MBR of the first drive?