# Cannot Run Ubuntu After Clean Install on Toshiba Satellite

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I am having trouble booting Ubuntu from my Toshiba Satellite (S-50 Series Laptop).

During the installation, I chose to delete Windows and have Ubuntu as the only OS on the system. I think this is called a clean install but correct me if I'm wrong (as I'm new).

After the installation, when I turn on the laptop I get this :

[image: message]
I then looked for some answers to this and I learned how to access the BIOS on my laptop. Many tutorials [such as this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815027/ubuntu-16-04-wont-boot-when-installed-after-windows-10) suggested that I go to the *Security* tab and then select *Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing*.

For some reason my laptop doesn't seem to have this option. I tried setting up a BIOS Supervisor password :

[image]. You can see that the Supervisor password is registered but there is no option to *Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing*. The options that do appear (Boot Menu, BIOS User Password permission, etc.) can only be toggled to Enabled or Disabled.

I then tried to look if there was anything in the other tabs. Under the *Advanced* tab there is a *System Configuration* option :

[image] Clicking that option, I then get into this :

[image]. When I click *Boot Mode*, there are only two options: *UEFI Boot* or *CSM Boot*. I still cannot seem to find *Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing*.

What should I do? Is there any other way I can get Ubuntu up and running on my hard drive? I can run from the USB just fine but I can't seem to run it on the hardware.

Thank you.

Comment: The "Trusted..." is a vendor specific modification (Acer?), so not appearing on your Toshiba is not a surprise.  May the /EFI file is missing because the install was legacy, not UEFI, try setting to CSM mode and see if boot then works.

Comment: Go to BIOS and reset it to factory settings, set UEFI boot (not CSM), turn off Secure Boot and Fast boot (if it exists), boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, use `gparted` to install a fresh GPT partition table (**this will wipe the drive**), and reinstall Ubuntu. Report back.

Comment: @ubfan1 so when I set it to CSM and then restarted my laptop, the laptop keeps prompting me to insert media

Comment: @heynnema so in gparted I just do _Create Partition Table_ ? I don't need to select a previous partition? I have a picture of what I mean but idk how to post a picture to a comment.

Comment: No, you don't need to select any partition when you create a new partition table. Select GPT table. Understand that this will wipe the drive, and prepare it for a clean Ubuntu install.

Comment: @heynnema I just tried what you suggested but I still get the error message from my original post. It always seems like my computer is checking for a USB and not running from hard drive. Is there anything else that you suggest I try?

Comment: It doesn't run from the hard drive. You booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, yes? You started `gparted`, yes? You selected your hard disk drive in the pop up in the upper-right of the `gparted` window, yes? You went to the Device menu and selected create new partition table, yes?

Comment: Yes I did all of that. I have a picture of it but I'm unsure how to post it to the comments. Right now I'm trying something from a different thread in which they try to boot through CSM like @ubfan1 suggested

Comment: No, don't boot via CSM. Don't follow multiple instructions at the same time.

Comment: Post images to imgur.com.

Comment: @heynnema I changed the boot to CSM and then  reinstalled Ubuntu and now it works. Thank you guys for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend you to boot Ubuntu as LEGACY BIOS rather than UEFI. It works best and you also have an option of dual/triple boot.

If your laptop is new, chances are that their is a UEFI and OEM partition already set-up which prevents installation of other OS. You can use the diskpart utility in windows (reinstall windows and delete the partitions) and then install ubuntu.

In your BIOS, select the boot option as Legacy. You have set it to UEFI. Try booting now. If it still doesn't work, then re-insert your bootable USB and then I suggest making manual partitions. Select `create new partition table`. In this menu, you will get to know if Windows is properly removed or not. Now you can install ubuntu by making the boot, root and home partitions.